# Install own deployed app from Windows Phone Store

Tags: windows-phone-store

I had published a payed app the first time. Is there a way to download and install the (my own) app without paying for it?

If I click the buy button, the store shows me only the regular price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer in the official [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b9c9c50f-9f8f-4954-b776-67ea83748d11/downloading-own-payed-app-for-free?forum=wpsubmit#b9c9c50f-9f8f-4954-b776-67ea83748d11). There is no way to download the app without purchasing.